# VTK 3D Volume Rendering from Memory

Tags: c++, vtk

I am going to render 3D Data, which is a one dimensional array. This data are precomputed in the same program that will do the visualization. The data represents an uniform 3D grid. Each cell of the grid consists of a vector.

```
GridSize = dx * dy * dz * 3
```

How can I visualize this array without copying by VTK?
Please, provide a short sequence of VTK invocation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
int dx = 10, dy = 10, dz = 10;

vtkSmartPointer <vtkImageData> image =
  vtkSmartPointer <vtkImageData>::New();
image->SetDimensions(dx, dy, dz);
image->AllocateScalars(VTK_DOUBLE, 3);

double * Grid = reinterpret_cast<double*>(image->GetScalarPointer());
populate(Grid,dx,dy,dz);
```